# Rotation matrix for a bicycle

Tags: graphics, physics, vector, matrix

Assume you have a flat plane, with a bicycle resting on it.  As the bicycle enters a turn, it leans into the turn with angle theta.  At the same time, the bike frame points in the same direction as the bike velocity.

Thus, given the bike velocity vector v (assumed to be in the XZ plane) and the lean angle theta, how can you find the rotation matrix for the bike?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @Ignacio: mathoverflow is for graduate-level mathematics, not things like this

Comment: The bike will fall over. You need a handlebar angle relative to the bird's eye view as well as a lean angle relative to the driver behind bicyclist's view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a quaternion. Axis is bike velocity and 'lean into turn' is axis angle.
[Then convert to rotation matrix](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToMatrix/index.htm)